# Top Command - How to reduce the displayed Columns

Tags: top, columns

Can we get specific column in a top command,  for eg I'm interested in only the memory utilization and CPU usage column.

How do I reduce the displayed columns of the top command to only the above two columns?

Comment: What OS? What `top` variant? There are dozens of top implementations.

Comment: Please provide us your OS and top version (`top -h`).

Answer (score 24):

**NOTE:** Assuming you have this version of [`top` (procps)](http://procps.sourceforge.net). You can check with this command:

```
$ top --version
    top: procps version 3.2.8
usage:  top -hv | -bcisSH -d delay -n iterations [-u user | -U user] -p pid [,pid ...]
```

procps is often the version of `top` included with Fedora/CentOS/RHEL and other variants.

#### Changing columns

If you look in the man page for `top` you'll see a section titled: "2b. SELECTING and ORDERING Columns". There are keyboard shortcuts for toggling visibility for the different fields/columns.

For example:

```
  f,o     . Fields/Columns: 'f' add or remove; 'o' change display order
  F or O  . Select sort field
  <,>     . Move sort field: '<' next col left; '>' next col right
```

You can use the key <kbd>f</kbd> while in `top` to get to a secondary screen where you can specify which columns should be toggled visible or not:

For example:

```
Current Fields:  ANOPQRSTUVbcdefgjlmyzWHIKX  for window 3:Mem
Toggle fields via field letter, type any other key to return 

* A: PID        = Process Id                                      * W: S          = Process Status
* N: %MEM       = Memory usage (RES)                              * H: PR         = Priority
* O: VIRT       = Virtual Image (kb)                              * I: NI         = Nice value
* P: SWAP       = Swapped size (kb)                               * K: %CPU       = CPU usage
* Q: RES        = Resident size (kb)                              * X: COMMAND    = Command name/line
* R: CODE       = Code size (kb)
...
```

There are more, these are just a sample. When you're done toggling the columns the way you want, use the <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get out of the selection screen.

#### Saving configuration

You can use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to save your changes so they're the defaults:

```
  W         Write configuration file
```

The file is stored here, `$HOME/.toprc`, and looks like this:

```
$ more .toprc 
RCfile for "top with windows"       # shameless braggin'
Id:a, Mode_altscr=0, Mode_irixps=1, Delay_time=1.000, Curwin=2
Def fieldscur=AEHIoqTWKNMBcdfgjpLrsuvyzX
    winflags=129016, sortindx=19, maxtasks=0
    summclr=2, msgsclr=5, headclr=7, taskclr=7
Job fieldscur=ABcefgjlrstuvyzMKNHIWOPQDX
    winflags=63416, sortindx=13, maxtasks=0
    summclr=6, msgsclr=6, headclr=7, taskclr=6
Mem fieldscur=ANOPQRSTUVbcdefgjlmyzWHIKX
    winflags=65464, sortindx=13, maxtasks=0
    summclr=5, msgsclr=5, headclr=4, taskclr=5
Usr fieldscur=ABDECGfhijlopqrstuvyzMKNWX
    winflags=65464, sortindx=12, maxtasks=0
    summclr=3, msgsclr=3, headclr=2, taskclr=7
```

See section 5 of the man page for more details, "5. FILES".

Comment: Is there a way to change the columns/field via a command line flag? This would be really useful, for instance for checking top on different machines and getting a standardised output.

Comment: @naught101 - if you have a new question ask it on the main site. Comments aren't really meant for that.

Answer (score 3):

**[Centos-6 | Ubuntu 12.10] This cmd print 4 top processes sort by CPU USAGE**

```
top -bn 1 | grep "^ " | awk '{ printf("%-8s  %-8s  %-8s\n", $9, $10, $12); }' | head -n 5
```

**Output**

```
%CPU      %MEM      COMMAND
7.7       0.2       top
0.0       0.3       init
0.0       0.0       kthreadd
0.0       0.0       migration/0
```

*Note: head -n 5 instead of 4 because we also have column name*

*columns $9, $10, $12 means CPU, MEM, COMMAND. Use 'top' command to get column numbers*

**Sort by MEMORY USAGE (your 'top' must support -m to run this)**

```
# this work on my centos-6 machine, NOT work on my Ubuntu 12.10
top -m -bn 1 | grep "^ " | awk '{ printf("%-8s  %-8s  %-8s\n", $9, $10, $12); }' | head -n 5
```

Comment: Which version of top is this?

Comment: I used centos-6.4. The top command on Ubuntu dont support -m for sorting my memory usage.

Comment: Interesting, I'm on Fedora (14), I'm getting procps' version of top. I just double checked and on CentOS 5 + 6 they're using top procps as well. Your command didn't work on F14. It does work on CentOS 5 + 6 though. Just an FYI for anyone that comes across this thread!

Answer (score 1):

to view in json format and removing header as well,

```
top -bn 1 | grep "^ " | awk '{ printf("%s%s%s\n","{CPU:"$9",","MEM:"$10",","CMD:"$12"}"); }' | head -n 6 | tail -n +2
```

output like below,

```
{CPU:6.4,MEM:0.3,CMD:gnome-terminal}
{CPU:6.4,MEM:1.9,CMD:chrome}
{CPU:0.0,MEM:0.0,CMD:init}
{CPU:0.0,MEM:0.0,CMD:kthreadd}
{CPU:0.0,MEM:0.0,CMD:ksoftirqd/0}
```

Comment: Your `grep | awk | head | tail` can be coalesced into a single `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

```
top -stats pid,cpu,threads,mem,purg,vsize,time,state
```

[`man top`](https://ss64.com/osx/top.html) and look for `-o` for the list of supported keys (=columns).

Answer (score 0):

**Command line configuration**
I did not want to affect my whole user by overwriting the user `.toprc`, so I came up with an solution to have a separate configuration per use-case.
You can make `top` use a custom configuration file instead of the one in your users home directory.
Just change the `HOME` variable to a custom directory containing the `.toprc` file for your needs.

```bash
# TOPRC_PROFILE_DIRECTORY contains .toprc (or can be created by saving using shift+w after configuring using keybindings) 
TOPRC_PROFILE_DIRECTORY="<your-directory>"
HOME="$TOPRC_PROFILE_DIRECTORY" top
```