# Start top with particular sorting

Tags: top

I'd like to start `top` with sorting set to resident memory size, instead of the default CPU usage.

I don't see a way to do that from command line arguments or startup file. Obviously I can't `echo "Oq" | top` either since I'd prevent `top` from using the tty.

Is there a way to do this?

Update: I run `top` on Linux (recent Ubuntu and Debian, 3.x kernels), installed e.g. as 'procps 1:3.2.8-11ubun', though I suppose that the column ordering functionality might be pretty cross-platform.

Comment: What OS are you using? The details will likely depend on your `top` implementation.

Comment: Some more interesting read of varying behaviours of `top` is observed [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86591/47538).

Comment: @Ramesh: aha, `Shift+W` works with my version and saves the settings as default, restored at the next start! Please update your answer so that I could accept it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`top -M` sorts by resident memory usage.

> M
> sort tasks by resident memory usage.

This is the version of top on my system.

> top -v
> top: procps version 3.2.7

If your Linux distribution supports the `-M` flag, you could use it as mentioned [here](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm).

However, if your `top` doesn't support the `-M` flag, you could launch your `top` command and get into the interactive mode by typing <kbd>h</kbd> to check the sort field. (I assume it is the same across various distributions)

In my system (rather the `top` version of my system), I could type <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>O</kbd> to select the sorting field and key  <kbd>Q</kbd> of my `top` version lets me sort on resident memory.

If you want to save your configuration you could do something as mentioned by slm [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86591/47538).

#### Saving configuration

You can use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to save your changes so they're the defaults:

```
  W         Write configuration file
```

The file is stored in `$HOME/.toprc` or `$HOME/.config/procps/toprc` (in procps-ng 3.3.13 or later), and looks like this:

```
$ more toprc 
RCfile for "top with windows"       # shameless braggin'
Id:a, Mode_altscr=0, Mode_irixps=1, Delay_time=1.000, Curwin=2
Def fieldscur=AEHIoqTWKNMBcdfgjpLrsuvyzX
    winflags=129016, sortindx=19, maxtasks=0
    summclr=2, msgsclr=5, headclr=7, taskclr=7
Job fieldscur=ABcefgjlrstuvyzMKNHIWOPQDX
    winflags=63416, sortindx=13, maxtasks=0
    summclr=6, msgsclr=6, headclr=7, taskclr=6
Mem fieldscur=ANOPQRSTUVbcdefgjlmyzWHIKX
    winflags=65464, sortindx=13, maxtasks=0
    summclr=5, msgsclr=5, headclr=4, taskclr=5
Usr fieldscur=ABDECGfhijlopqrstuvyzMKNWX
    winflags=65464, sortindx=12, maxtasks=0
    summclr=3, msgsclr=3, headclr=2, taskclr=7
```

See section 5 of the man page for more details, "5. FILES".

Comment: Hmm, my build of `top` does not seem to support it, though it reports version 3.2.8.

Answer (score 3):

On my linux system, `top` (procps-ng version 3.3.9) has an `-o` switch:

```
   -o  :Override-sort-field as:  -o fieldname
        Specifies  the  name  of  the  field  on  which tasks will be
        sorted, independent of what is reflected in the configuration
        file.  You can prepend a '+' or '-' to the field name to also
        override the sort direction.  A leading '+' will force  sort‐
        ing  high  to  low,  whereas  a '-' will ensure a low to high
        ordering.
```

So, `top -o RES` starts `top` sorted by resident memory size.

Answer (score 0):

You've got `top -a` on Linux. Try checking manpages on Unix its `top -m`. Not sure if we are talking about the same memory.

Comment: FYI, there are differing versions of top on various Linux distros, so you might want to make your A more specific.